# Is There a way to have the selected option be the default value upon refreshing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this problem today, I wanted my selected option would be the default value upon refresh of my page. For example I have this:

```
<select id="options">
<option value="0">Apple</option> 
<option value="1">Orange</option> 
<option value="2">Mango</option></select>
```

the default on my UI is Apple, so what I want is when I clicked Orange option it will be the default value when I refresh the page. Is there a way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Use a cookie to store the selected option and set it same on page reload.

Answer (score 6):

I think local storage can help to you. 
So for example:

```
<select id="options">
<option value="0">Apple</option> 
<option value="1">Orange</option> 
<option value="2">Mango</option></select>
```

Javascript

```
$("#options").on("change", function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    // save to local
    if(window.localStorage){
        window.localStorage.setItem("#options-val", val);
    }
});

if(window.localStorage){
    var item = window.localStorage.getItem("#options-val");
    if(item) $("#options").val(item);
}
```

And see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a4D5Q/)

All your js code must be inside $(document).ready()

After run code on demo, try to reload page and you will see the result!

Comment: Fiddle is empty FUserThrowError

Comment: @user3213861 i forgot add link ))

Comment: `localStorage` is an HTML5 feature.

Comment: @SyncCircles if you read question, you can find that there's nothing about requirements!

Comment: @FUserThrowError : I agree. I just mentioned it as a additional info.

Comment: One suggestion: use `sessionStorage` instead of `localStorage`.  (Otherwise, syntax is exactly the same.)  It'll last only until the browser closes.

Answer (score 0):

use onchange to set a session cookie then set option.selected when the page loads

```
<select id="options" onChange="document.cookie='fruit='+this.value;">
<option value="0">Apple</option> 
<option value="1">Orange</option> 
<option value="2">Mango</option></select>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function getCookie(cname)
{
/* http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp */
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++)
  {
  // var c = ca[i].trim(); // trim not supported on IE8
  var c = ca[i].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'');
  if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
  }
return "";
} 
window.onload = function() {
    var v = getCookie('fruit');
    if (v) document.getElementById('options').options[v].selected = true;
}
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Set selected="selected" for the option you want to be the default.

```
<option selected="selected">
  default
</option>
```